# Notificação em uma rede local com PostgreSQL

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Eu gostaria de saber como posso enviar uma simples notificação para usuários de uma rede local, mandar uma notificação para todos os outros dispositivos com o app conectado ao banco PostgreSQL...

Comment: Recomendo você criar uma aplicação para isso, que conecta ao banco e manda a notificação via [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No PostgreSQL`(Versao >= 9.1)` você pode fazer uso do par `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` para fazer algo desse tipo.

Essas funções possibilitam que clientes conectados ao banco recebam notificações assíncronas através de um canal específico.

Por exemplo, os clientes conectados ao banco de dados que estiverem escutando o canal `foobar`, serão capazes de receber as notificações:

```
LISTEN foobar;
```

Para notificar os clientes que estiverem escutando no canal `foobar`:

```
NOTIFY foobar, 'Oi, eu sou uma notificacao!';
```

Caso você queira que um determindo cliente não escute mais o canal de notificações `foobar`:

```
UNLISTEN foobar;
```

Referência:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html

Espero ter ajudado!